# How to extend an SVG graphic downwards filling the page?

Tags: html, css, web, svg, graphics

In HTML, I am trying to use SVG graphics to create a background section to a part of my site. It uses a curve that sections off a part of the website to another. I have managed to create a basic outline for the general shape of the SVG: [Picture of the animated banner and SVG page section.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihuTs.png)

However, I am expecting the SVG element to be stretched downwards so it fills out the rest of the page. This is not the case however as when scrolling down the SVG ends and the background takes up the rest of the site: [The SVG is too small.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jU1w.png)

I need help extending the SVG to fill the rest of the page underneath it.

Current HTML Code:

```
div class="wave">
      <svg width="100%" height="200px" fill="none" version="1.1"
       xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <path 
          fill="white" 
          d="
            M0 67
            C 273,183
              822,-90
              2525.01,98
            V 359
            H 0 
            V 67
            Z">
        </path>
      </svg>
    </div>
```

I have tried to change the SVG values but they normally just turn the graphic out of shape. I would like help understanding how to understand and fix this problem.

Futhermore, how to use the SVG viewBox to preserve the aspect ratio of the graphic?

[Update] Here is the website so far. I need to move the SVG graphic downwards as indicated in the arrow so the black particle background is above it: [Picture Update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZiLMi.png)

Comment: probably easiest to provide a viewBox that fits the path and then decide if you want the aspect ratio preserved (i.e. decide which preserveAspectRatio setting you want).

Comment: Oh, I never knew about the viewbox. I will modify the question to ask about how to use one for this.

Comment: Best set a viewBox and experiment with its values. See https://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/IG/resources/svgprimer.html#coordinate for more information about viewBox

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/preserveAspectRatio

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I thought about your problem.

If the idea is to have an image fullscreen on home with a wave svg down with a color and continuity same color in other part. An idea would be the following:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

section {
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: #999999;
  margin: 0;
}

section h2 {
  margin: 0;
}

#home {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/1920/1080");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  position: relative;
}

#home .title {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: #7b98bc;
}

.wave {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.wave svg {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<section id="home">
  <div class="wave">
    <svg width="100%" height="auto" fill="#999999" viewbox="0 0 512 128" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMax meet" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <path d="M 0,75 C 158.44341,97.135847 296.6677,25.650819 512,25 V 128 H 0 Z"/>
        </svg>
  </div>
  <div class="title">
    <h2>Title of my website</h2>
  </div>
</section>

<section id="part1">
  <h2>here we are section part1</h2>
</section>
```

Comment: Thank you! That works apart from one thing but we are so close now. I need to move the background image below the svg graphic. I have another background using tsparticles that is above it. So how do we move the background below the SVG? I have added a picture in the question of what my page looks like so far.

Comment: try to change .wave 100%, 100% to width: 100vw, height: 100vh

Comment: This is great apart from it moves the svg not the background image.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is you can (see thereafter) "fill" till the end of page, now that means playing with viewport and aspect ratio as said Robert. That means also your "curve" won't be constant regarding different sizes of screen.

Check and play with the snippet thereafter:

```css
.wave {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="wave">
  <svg width="auto" height="100%" fill="none" viewbox="0 0 512 128" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin slice">
    <path
            fill="red"
            d="M 0,75 C 158.44341,97.135847 296.6677,25.650819 512,25 V 128 H 0 Z">
    </path>
</svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have any alternatives then to fill the graphic downwards until the end of the page to give consistency?

Comment: I would say, make the svg with the curve which grow on the width, add under this one svg rectangle which will fill till end of page.

Comment: As this is a graphical work perhaps giving a graphical demonstration can be more helpful to me and the community? Or perhaps creating the correct SVG. Currently its too small.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps this can work for you

you have your wave, plus a rect under

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.wave {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wave">
  <svg width="auto" height="100%" fill="#ff0000" viewbox="0 0 512 128" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path d="M 0,75 C 158.44341,97.135847 296.6677,25.650819 512,25 V 128 H 0 Z"></path>
    <rect width="512" height="129" x="0" y="127" />
</svg>
</div>
```

Comment: This is definitely on the right path! However expanding the rectangle height and width up to a certain point works but if the height goes above around 100 it does not increase in size. Are there any other variables to edit apart from the rect width and size?

Comment: if I understand well what you are looking for, I think it'll better to use a clip path... you have your background-image with the curve clip-path, and a background color. So your image will be clipped under the curve showing the background color. Div with this background color can go till the end of document

Comment: Thank you for your time, I have a question: The clip path is slightly different than SVG I take it? So what would this look like in code form?